# Why would Pycharm expected type warnings start suddenly appearing?

Tags: pycharm, python-3.6

Just recently Pycharm (2018.3.5 on OS X) started warning all over my code base with Expected Type warnings. I thought at first it may have been due to an upgrade or other change, but I have tried multiple previous versions and it the previously non-existant warnings are still all over my code base.

Here is a particularly egregious example. The code:

```
import time 
x= int(time.time())
```

results in the following warning:

> Expected type 'Union[str, bytes, SupportsInt]', got 'float' instead
>   less... (⌃F1)  Inspection info: This inspection detects type errors in
>   function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing,
>   this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Types of
>   function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3
>   function annotations.

I should note, Pycharm is highlighting `time.time()` as the problematic section of code.

Is it possible I have corrupted some internal cache? Note, I also deleted the Pycharm folders in ~/Library thinking maybe I had messed with some preferences, but also to no avail.

Comment: Can you try doing `File -> Invalidates caches and restart`. If often solves this kind of issues.

Comment: I did not know that existed (nor what it actually does). Unfortunately it did not resolve the issue.